# How to display mysql database entries in unordered list, 3 to a row in descending order using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am just learning PHP and have decided to create a blog. I have figured out how to create a database and add entries to it. but am having trouble figuring out how to display those entries in an organized manner.

this is where I have gotten so far:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'password') ;
mysql_select_db ('db');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbp_blog ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entries from table tbp_blog.<br />" .    $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $date = date("l F d Y g:i:s A", $row['timestamp']);

    $link = $row['link'];
    $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $description = stripslashes($row['description']);
    $entry = stripslashes($row['entry']);
    $image_link = $row['image_link'];
    $image_alt = $row['image_alt'];
    ?>
<ul class="submissions">
    <li class="first">
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
    <img alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" class="blog_image" height="198" src="<?php echo $image_link; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" width="276" /></a>          
<div class="submissions_content">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
        </div>

    </li></ul> 
    <div class="hr">
        <img class="star" src="images/star.png" width="40" height="12" alt="Star" /></div>

<?php
}
?>
```

this is a link to a page that is an example of exactly what I am trying to get:

http://wearepandr.com/blog

how can I get my entries to display in descending order, in rows of three, with a limit of 9 entries per page. As well as automatically creating the next page and so on. I see that they have used li classes first second and last for the order of each row.

I am also wanting to format my time stamp so that it indicates to time in my timezone Vancouver BC. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Mario

Comment: an unordered list in descending order. eh?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have so far? Also @Strawberry probably meant this as a joke, but his point is valid. The point of an **unordered** list is that the order has no meaning. Are you sure you don't want an **ordered** list?

Comment: Also, if you can still change, [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in PDO

First, connecting to the database:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$database = 'db_name';
$db_username = 'username';
$db_password = 'password';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database";
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    //You can do what you like with any error messages (echo, store, etc)
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Next, creating the function that will have the query in it:

Query Functions go in the Model (MVC)

```
//Use a function that can accept parameters (users id, search term, etc)
//For your question, there are no parameters
function getPosts() {
    global $db;
    global $database;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $database.tbp_blog ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5";
    //If your query was more complex, you would need to learn about binding values
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $posts = array();
        //Depending on how many posts you have, you can do fetch or fetchAll
        //fetchAll is faster to write but here is the approach with fetch
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        while ($result != NULL){
            $posts[] = $result;
            $result = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        //Free up resources
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        //return it to where it was called from
        //send back the array we created
        return $posts;
     }
    //Catch any errors
    catch (PDOException $exc) {
        return '0';
    }
}
```

Call the function

Usually this goes in the controller (MVC)

```
//Call the function to get posts with no parameters
//The variable "posts" here will become the returned "posts" array from our function
$posts = getPosts();
```

This is in the HTML section of your site:

This is in the view (MVC)

```
<?php
if (empty($posts)) {
    echo 'There are no results';
}
else {
    echo '<ul class="submissions">';
    //You can decide what type of loop to use
    foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
        <li class="first"><a href="<?php echo $post['link']; ?>"> <img alt="<?php echo $post['image_alt']; ?>" class="blog_image" height="198" src="<?php echo $post['image_link']; ?>" title="<?php echo $post['title']; ?>" width="276" /></a>
          <div class="submissions_content">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $post['link']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo $post['description']; ?></p>
          </div>
        </li>
<?php } 
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

This code looks like much more than it is because I added in a fair amount of comments for you to read while implementing it in your site.

If you are going to be creating a blog, it would be very wise to learn about the Model View Controller (MVC) for organizing and using your code. Most blogs are built that way.

Comment: After further examination of your solution. I find that it is not really what I was looking for. It does not really address my question as how to display my posts in the manner that it is done on the wearepndr.com site. It seems you have sent me in an entirely different direction. Please follow the link and if you can help me achieve that I would really appreciate it.